# Text scrolling on video using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, video-streaming

i am using tkinter and PIL image to play video, i want to scroll text at the bottom of the video like news scroll.. in multiple languages, how can i achieve it.. can please somebody give an idea on as i am a newbie to GUI.

for scrolling:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

# width=width chars, height=lines text
text = tk.Text(root, width=20, height=1,fg = 'white', bg='black')
text.pack()

# use a proportional font to handle spaces correctly
text.config(font=('Devlys 010', 24, 'bold'))

s1 = "fcuk fVdV\n;k=k djuk n.Muh; vijk/k gSA"
# pad front and end with 20 spaces
s2 = ' ' * 20
s = s2 + s1 + s2

for k in range(len(s)):
    # use string slicing to do the trick
    ticker_text = s[k:k+20]
    text.insert("1.1", ticker_text)
    root.update()
    # delay by 0.15 seconds
    time.sleep(0.15)

root.mainloop()
```

i tried like this. i am able to get the text scrolling but i could not embed it with the video.

for video:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkvideo import tkvideo

root = Tk()
my_label = Label(root)
my_label.pack()
player = tkvideo("video.mp4", my_label, loop = 1, size = (1280,720))
player.play()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Post the code on playing video as well

Comment: please check now..

Comment: Since you have used external module to play the video, you cannot embed text into the video directly.  Suggest to place another `Label` on top of the video label for the scrolling text.

Comment: i am facing issues with that only, i was not able to create a label on top of the video.. can i get any reference for that please?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used external module `tkvideo` to play the video, you cannot embed text into the video directly.

Suggest to create another label and place on top of the video as below:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkvideo import tkvideo

root = tk.Tk()

# for video
my_label = tk.Label(root, bd=0)
my_label.pack()

# for scrolling text
scroll_label = tk.Text(root, fg="white", bg="black", width=20, height=1, bd=0)
scroll_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=1, y=-10, anchor="s")

player = tkvideo("video.mp4", my_label, loop=1, size=(640,480))
player.play()

# the scrolling text
pad = " " * 20
txt = pad + "fcuk fVdV\n;k=k djuk n.Muh; vijk/k gSA" + pad

def update_text(n=0):
    scroll_label.delete("1.0", "end")
    scroll_label.insert("1.0", txt[n:n+20])
    root.after(150, update_text, (n+1)%len(txt))

update_text() # start scrolling text
root.mainloop()
```